# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint permutations, then $\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Consider the permutations on the set $I = \{1,2,3....,n\}$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint permutations on $I$, then they commute with respect to function composition.

---

My Proof Attempt:

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be disjoint permutations. Then, $\forall k \in I: \alpha(k) = k \lor \beta(k) = k$.

Suppose that $\alpha(k) = k$. Then:

$\forall k \in I: \alpha(\beta(k)) = \beta(k)$

$\forall k \in I: \beta(\alpha(k)) = \beta(k)$

Hence:

$\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$

Now, suppose that $\beta(k) = k$. Then:

$\forall k \in I: \alpha(\beta(k)) = \alpha(k)$

$\forall k \in I: \beta(\alpha(k)) = \alpha(k)$

Hence:

$\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$

This proves that they commute under function composition.

Could someone check my proof above and see if it works or not? Otherwise, how could I improve it? How could I improve my style of presentation? Is it too untidy or unreadable?

Comment: Note that $(\forall k) (p(k) \lor q(k))$ does **not** imply $((\forall k) p(k)) \lor ((\forall k) q(k))$. A newborn is either a male or a female, that does not mean all are male or all are female...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ? Wot? Where did I mess up with regards to that?

Comment: As Jean says, your quantifiers are a bit confused. It is not correct to write "$\forall k \in I:  \alpha(\beta(k)) = \beta(k)$" after writing "suppose  $\alpha(k) = k$" (can you come up with a counterexample?). You should just leave off the $\forall$ here. You might write at the start "let $k$ be arbitrary" and then split into cases for *that specific* $k$. Also, I think you need to do just a little more explanation of why $\alpha(\beta(k)) = \beta(k)$ in the first case (ie, why does $\alpha$ fix $\beta(k)$?)

Comment: Your first step was good.  You then want to say what happens in each case, $\alpha(k)=k$, or, on the other hand, $\beta(k)=k$.  You do this for one $k$ at a time, and thus prove the result.  You wrote  $\forall k$ on the second and third line incorrectly.  Now, how do you know $\alpha$ doesn't move $\beta(k)$?  It's because they're disjoint: wherever $\beta$ moves $k$, it's to an $l$ that $\alpha$ fixes.  From this it follows that both sides agree on $k$.  Now do the same for arbitrary $k$ such that $\beta(k)=k$.  Finally, since every $k$ is fixed by either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, we're done.

Comment: Hmm @IzaakvanDongen I don't quite see a counterexample here? So, like, $\beta(k) \in I$. The reason for that is because $\beta$ is a permutation $\beta:I \to I$. Since it is in I, it follows naturally that $\alpha(\beta(k)) = \beta(k)$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Oh so i suppose that $\beta(k) = k$. Then, $\beta(\alpha(k)) = \alpha(k)$ because they're disjoint and since $\alpha(k) \in I$, it follows that $\beta(\alpha(k))$ maps $\alpha(k)$ to itself. Furthermore, $\alpha(\beta(k)) = \alpha(k)$ because we supposed that $\beta(k) = k$. Would that be fine or no?

Comment: By the way, I do get the reason why my quantification is wrong. My book uses the definition "Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be permutations. Then, they are disjoint if for all k in I, $\alpha(k) = k$ or $\beta(k) = k$. I'm starting to think that i should interpret that as a XOR, rather than an OR?

Comment: Ah I meant to look for a counterexample to $\forall k \in I: \beta(\alpha(k)) = \beta(k)$, I think. I'm afraid that "since $\beta(k) \in I$, it follows naturally that $\alpha(\beta(k)) = \beta(k)$" is incorrect. $\alpha$ does not fix everything in $I$, since then $\alpha$ would have to be the identity permutation, which it isn't necessarily (eg $\alpha = (1\ 2), \beta = (3\ 4)$. You're getting the fact that everything is either fixed by $\alpha$ or $\beta$ mixed up with the statement that either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ fixes everything.

Comment: Your book certainly does mean the normal mathematical interpretation of "or" - ie *at least* one of these is true.

Comment: Whatever $\beta(k)$ is, $\alpha$ fixes, because they're disjoint.  That is, say $\beta(k)=l$.  Now since $\beta$ is a permutation, $\beta$ must move $l$.  That is, $\beta(l)\ne l$.  But then by disjointness, $\alpha(l)=l$.

Comment: This is assuming of course that they don't both fix $k$.

Comment: Ah it seems like there was nothing wrong with the argument that I made just now in the comments. I'm gonna have to let this churn in my mind for a bit so that I can fully grasp it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the proof below is taken from your proof.

This presentation might not the be the best one, and you might find different style of proofs that you might appreciate more, but still hope that this example may help you :

---

1. It suffices to show that :

   $$\text{For each }k\in I\text{, we have }\alpha\beta(k)=\beta\alpha(k)$$

   (If you want to be more clear, you may also add "Since $S_n$ acts faithfully on the set $I$")
2. Since $\alpha,\beta$ are disjoint, we have the following :

   $$\text{Each element in }I\text{ is fixed either by }\alpha\text{ or by }\beta.$$
3. Pick $k\in I$. Interchange $\alpha,\beta$ if necessary, we may assume $k$ is fixed by $\alpha$. We have

   $$\beta\alpha(k)=\beta(k)$$

   If we can show that either $\alpha$ fixes $\beta(k)$ or $\beta$ fixes $k$, then we are done, since either cases implies

   $$\beta(k)=\alpha\beta(k)$$
4. Suppose $\alpha$ doesn't fix $\beta(k)$, then we have $\beta(\beta(k))=\beta(k)$ (since $\alpha,\beta$ are disjoint)

   but since $\beta$ is a permutation, we must have from the identity $\beta(\beta(k))=\beta(k)$ that $\beta(k)=k$.

Therefore, we are done.

Comment: Oof that's interesting hmm. I'm gonna have to study that in more detail afterwards. Thank you for the proof!